# W3C Total Cache Minify in Admin Page

Tags: wordpress, admin, minify

I have a question. I use the plugin `W3C Total Cache` and it works great !

I noted that it works only on website but not on the admin page...

How can I do to minify Admin Page with W3 please ?

Thanks !

Comment: Using a caching system in the admin area (where all the content is highly dynamic and might change on every view) will probably not make much sense.

Comment: Yes but I just need to "minify" not cache..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WP interface files don't have a ton of whitespace in them, so I doubt you'd see much improvement. The CSS and JS are minified as much as possible already.

However, this would be fairly impossible on many pages, such as any page implementing the WP editor. Line endings are required to display the editor correctly, therefore you'd be breaking functionality.

You may be able to do gzip compression through a .htaccess file if you're terribly concerned with efficiency, but it seems quite unnecessary. Compressing content takes time, and with dynamic content it's constantly changing, so recompressing it every time may actually increase page load time instead of decreasing it.